# probably pointer error Midi sysEx

Tags: swift, runtime-error, coremidi

I have an error code sometimes when I run my application with this code:

```
let letstryOtherThing: @convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDISysexSendRequest>) -> Swift.Void =
{ plop in
    print("here")
}

let rawPointer = UnsafeRawPointer([0xF0, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0xF7])
let pointer = rawPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)

let bytesToSend: UInt32 = 60
let complete: DarwinBoolean = false
let completionProc: MIDICompletionProc? = letstryOtherThing
let completionRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer? = nil
let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = pointer
let destination: MIDIEndpointRef = dest!
let reserved: (UInt8, UInt8, UInt8) = (0, 0 ,0)

var midiRequest:MIDISysexSendRequest = MIDISysexSendRequest(destination: destination, data: data, bytesToSend: bytesToSend, complete: complete, reserved: reserved, completionProc: completionProc!, completionRefCon: completionRefCon)

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    MIDISendSysex(&midiRequest)
})
```

The code is:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x800000020).

I use the library CoreMidi, if someone have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
It s because this var is local and its necessary to declare it in global.

```
var midiRequest:MIDISysexSendRequest = MIDISysexSendRequest(destination: destination, data: data, bytesToSend: bytesToSend, complete: complete, reserved: reserved, completionProc: completionProc!, completionRefCon: completionRefCon)
```